# Force Spring MVC controllers to Request scope

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Spring's default scope is `singleton`. However, for MVC controllers, which run to serve web requests and, in my project, may contain `@Autowired` prototype beans, I would like to force them by default to be at least `request`-scoped, if not prototype, **without** annotating each and every controller with `@Scope`

Do you think it is possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A composed annotation might be a good fit.

```
@Target(TYPE)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Controller
@Scope(WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST)
public @interface RequestScopedController { ... }
```

The controllers would use `@RequestScopedController` annotation instead of `@Controller`.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about composed annotations. I will probably accept this one if solution prevents name clashing (e.g. MainController-s under different packages)

Comment: Do you have any problems with the name clashing?

Comment: Yes. For example, I have multiple `MainController`s in several packages, named like that because they serve `/path/to/main` in several paths

Comment: If renaming the controllers is not an option, there's only one solution I know of - usage of `@Qualifier` annotation on both the controller and the property the controller is injected to.

Comment: Unfortunately @Qualifier on the controller does not work. I get a name conflict

Comment: Actually, `@Qualifier` is to be used only for `@Autowire`s

Answer (score 2):

you should add `@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` on your beans ( not controllers ) which are going to be autowired into your controller. This way, you inform spring to create proxy around your autowired bean - so its possible to use that in singleton class.